# Package CJK Error: Invalid character code

Tags: errors, symbols, code, cjk

Today, I use another computer to run my .tex. The console shows the following error.
[image]

But, I can run the same file on my foemer PC. After diagnosing, I find the problem which is marked below.
[image]

If I resave the file as UTF-8  encoding, the problem vanishes. Even if I can fix the problem, I still do not why such problem shows up. And, how can I fix the problem without resaving my .tex file?

I am using WinEdt 6.0 software for my regular latex typesetting. The operating system is windows 8. There are several PDF viewers in my computer. Default PDF viewer is Foxit Reader. So a newly generated PDF file is always opened in Foxit. Uninstalling Foxit software I have seen that the WinEdt can not able to give me the PDF file.

I want to open all my newly generated PDF files by Adobe Reader whereas Foxit will act as my default PDF viewer. How to change the settings of WinEdt to do it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: winedt 6.0 is *very* old and as far as I remember it can't handle cjk. You will have to get a newer editor.

Comment: As far as I know LaTeX only officially support UTF8 so if you use another encoding you're unsupported...